# JAVASCRIPT, WebdriverIO- How to interact with excel sheet using javascript code

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

How javascript code interacts with excel sheet to perform some operations like read, write and delete data from the sheet.
Please share dependency name and sample code(related to writing data to Excel sheet).

Answer (score 0):

Sheet.js - This is a very good excel library written in javascript. It works with different environments. They have a extensive documentation with many examples.

https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs is another wonderful library which I have used in the past. The documentation is extensive. They have nice examples as well.